# When I convert date and time in ISO format then every time I get 000Z?

Tags: angular

I am trying to convert with toISOString() function but every time I get 000Z "2020-12-25T09:22:23.000Z" at the end of stream.

```
    let dateStartValue = dateTime.dateStart;
let dateEndValue = dateTime.dateEnd;


let startTimeDate = dateStartValue.toISOString();
let endTimeDate = dateEndValue.toISOString();
```

OutPut -

2020-12-21T05:18:11.000Z
2020-12-25T09:21:23.000Z

Comment: that's the milliseconds of that date value. what about it ?

Comment: milliseconds is necessary for this ? My date is Thu Dec 24 2020 11:19:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) then I convert Iso string I get 2020-12-24T05:49:21.000Z. 
But I want some value in place of 000Z.

Comment: `const x = startTimeDate.substring(0, startTimeDate.length-5)` just remove it its a string

Comment: I apply 2020-09-07 12:38:27 from date time picker and then I convert into ISO format and I want "2020-09-07T12:38:27.912" but I got 2020-09-07T12:38:27.000Z.

Comment: your value simply does not contain milliseconds. where does `dateTime.dateStart` get its data from ?

Answer (score 1):

`toISOString()` returns UTC time. If you want your local time, you can do it with `toLocaleString()`